# Выполнение функций

Tags: javascript

Есть такие конструкции

```
(function (){alert('')}    ())

(function (){alert('')})    ()
```

Функции сразу выполняются.Сегодня встретил еще такой синтаксис

```
!function () {
    alert('')
}();

~function () {
    alert('')
}();
```

Что здесь происходит?Почему только такие символы "!,~"Как обусловленная их работа?
кто подскажет насколько валидно использовать такие варианты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если тебе не важен результат вызываемой функции, можно добавить впереди унарную операцию: `+ - ! ~`

а в остальном полностью аналог вызова функции в скобках

**т.е.:**

```
(function (){alert('')}()) // вызовет функцию и возвратит какой либо результат

!function (){alert('')}()  // вызовет функцию
```

**Например:**

```
var x = (function(a,b) { return a+b; }(5,4)); // вернет сумму
alert(x); // появится окошко с числом 9

// В случае с + - ! ~ стоит писать функции которые ничего не возвращают 
!function(a,b) { alert(a+b); }(5,4);
```

Comment: не совсем понял "не важен результат вызываемой функции"

Comment: щас, пример в ответ запишу.

Answer (score 1):

Это IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) - самовызывающаяся функция. Используется, чтобы создать отдельное пространство имён или сохранить значение переменной в замыкании. Почитайте, вот неплохая статья про иифи:

http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/